# request url with id between two expressions

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, http-request-parameters, get-mapping

I'm trying to call a url with an ID between /.

The url looks like this:
http://localhost:8080/chargeback/v1/dispute/22/events

and I need to recover that value 22 in the sysout from controller.

I know thats sounds very easy, but in my project i'm trying fix that w/ other programmers for many time.
Maybe some configuration i forgot.

Interface:

```
@RequestMapping("/dispute")
public interface disputeEvents{

    @GetMapping( value = "/{id}/events")
    ResponseEntity<Void> getDisputeEvents(@RequestParam Long id);

}
```

controller:

```
@Controller
public class testeController implements disputeEvents{

    @Override
    public ResponseEntity<Void> getDisputeEvents(Long id) {
    System.out.println(id);
    return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your interface and class as shown below code.

```
@RequestMapping("/default")
public interface disputeEvents {

    @GetMapping("/{id}/events")
    ResponseEntity<Void> getDisputeEvents(@PathVariable Long id);

}
```

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/dispute")
public class testeController implements disputeEvents {

    @Override
    public ResponseEntity<Void> getDisputeEvents(Long id) {
        System.out.println(id);
        return null;
    }
}
```

It will work fine for URL:http://localhost:8080/dispute/22/events.
If you want it to work for Url:http://localhost:8080/chargeback/v1/dispute/22/events, Change @RequestMapping("/dispute") to @RequestMapping("/chargeback/v1/dispute") in your controller class.

Comment: I tried as you said and it didn't work.
My code normally accesses the controller class/method, but when printing the value returns null.

Comment: It will work, Please check your interface and class once again maybe you have done any mistake because the Long value can't be null. Be sure that you have used @GetMapping( value = "/{id}/events") in interface not in the class.

Answer (score 0):

I put the @GetMapping("/{id}/events") inside controller.

Interface:

```
@RequestMapping("/default")
public interface disputeEvents {
    @GetMapping( value = "/{id}/events")
    ResponseEntity<Void> getDisputeEvents(@PathVariable(name = "id") Long id);
}
```

Controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/dispute")
public class testeController implements disputeEvents{
    @Override
    public ResponseEntity<Void> getDisputeEvents(@PathVariable(name = "id") Long id) {  
        System.out.println("teste:" + id);
        return null;
    }

}
```